# Hide an element when a toggle is checked in PHP/Laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel

I am trying to hide an element on my page when I click a toggle and unhide it when I click the toggle again. Here is my HTML code:

```html
<div class="form-group settings-row">
                {{ Form::label('notificationSettings', 'Notification Settings', array('class' => 'col-md-2 control-label')) }}
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <table style="border-width:0; margin-top:4px;">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                Notifications Enabled
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <div class="onoffswitch" style="margin:4px 0 0 7px;">
                                    <input type="checkbox" @if($notificationsEnabled == true)checked @endif name="notifications_toggle" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="notifications_toggle">
                                    <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="notifications_toggle">
                                        <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
                                        <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @foreach($notificationMessageRadios as $radio)
                            @if(isset($radio['text']))
                                <div class="row" style="margin-bottom:1em;">
                                    <input type='radio' name='notificationMessage' id="notificationmessage-other" value="" @if($radio['selected']) checked @endif> {{$radio['message']}}
                                </div>
                                <input type="text" id="notificationMessageCustom" placeholder="Pick your own!" @if($radio['selected'])value="{{ $settingsForMessages->notification_message }}" @else value="Pick your own!" @endif name="notificationMessageCustom" class="form-control" @if(!$radio['selected'])style="display:none"@endif>
                            @else
                                <div class="row">
                                    <input type='radio' name='notificationMessage' value="{{ $radio['message']}}" @if($radio['selected']) checked @endif> {{ $radio['message'] }}
                                </div>
                            @endif
                        @endforeach
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Breakdown:

So when I click the `onoffswitch` to be on, I want the radios to appear. When I click the `onoffswitch` to be off, I want the radios to disappear.

I am being thrown into this project, so this code already existed and I am being tasked with editing some features. Any kind of help would be greatly appreciated.

As a bonus, here is the controller side:

```js
$notificationsEnabled = ( $settings['notificationsEnabled'] == 1);

// Cast notification messages to a variable
        $notificationMessageMsgs = \Config::get('customer_messages.notificationMessageArray');
        $numNotificationMessageMsgs = count($notificationMessageMsgs);
        $notificationMessageSelected = false;

        // Determine which email subject radio button is checked
        foreach($notificationMessageMsgs as $index => $msg) {
            $isSelected = false;
            if ($settingsForMessages->notification_message == null && $index == 0) {
                $notificationMessageSelected = true;
                $isSelected = true;
            }
            if($msg['message'] === $settingsForMessages->notification_message){
                $isSelected = true;
                $notificationMessageSelected = true;
            }
            if($index == $numNotificationMessageMsgs - 1 && !$notificationMessageSelected){
                $isSelected = true;
            }
            $notificationMessageRadios[] = array_merge(['selected' => $isSelected], $msg);
        }
```

I am NOT looking for hand holding. I am looking for guidance, that is all.

Comment: You are going to need to use javascript for the front end to be responsive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try out jQuery?

Try out jQuery Toggle : https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/eff_toggle.asp

```
$("button").click(function(){
    $("p").toggle();
});
```

This is the code copies from the link . just target your "Class" , "ID" , "element" in the top row **$("button")** that needs to be clicked and than target the element that needs to be shown/hidden **$("p")**